# With CQL3 and comparator getting EOF error on create table

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I try running the following create table in cqlsh:

```
    CREATE TABLE measurements (metricid uuid, appid uuid, sourceid uuid, 
tagid uuid, day int, type int, PRIMARY KEY (metricid, appid, sourceid, 
tagid, day, type) WITH comparator=uuid);
```

I receive an error missing EOF at ')'.

As long as I do not include the WITH comparator I am fine, but I need the comparator.

I've tried a number of different combinations but can't seem to get this one correct.  What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I modified the query to work as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (metricid uuid, appid uuid, sourceid uuid, 
tagid uuid, day int, type int, sequence timeuuid, 
PRIMARY KEY ((metricid, appid, sourceid, tagid, day, type), sequence);
```

But I still would like to know what was incorrect with the first query.  According to the CQL3 specs: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/CREATE_COLUMNFAMILY it should work.

Comment: How is this question off topic?  Its a specific question (not subjective) about a language (CQL3) that is used in Cassandra.  Please explain to me how this specific question is off topic so I can avoid making the same mistake in the future.

Comment: I voted to close. The link you provided did not include any example like the one that didn't work for you, even though you claim that it did. The "off topic" close reason includes a sub category that says that the questioner should show that they have tried to understand the problem properly. The examples on that page clearly showed the `WITH` outside of the parentheses, and had you tried fixing that the error message you would then have gotten would have told you that the `comparator` property was not correct. You could have solved the problem yourself by reading the page you linked to.

Comment: I'm sorry but I respectfully disagree with you.  The comparator property seems to have been acceptable in 1.0 (http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/CREATE_COLUMNFAMILY). The 1.1 reference says nothing about comparator being dropped it just does not include the same example as existed in 1.0 so I assumed that comparator was included.  And to say that I did not try fixing the error is frankly insulting - I put up a sample that was one of the variations I tried and I tried quite a few over several hours.  Anyway, we'll just have to agree to disagree.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WITH` should go outside the parentheses, just like in the examples on the page you link to. Also, `comparator` is not a valid CQL3 option (and you specify the types of the columns so it would be superflous anyway), just remove it.

Comment: I tried inside and outside. However, you pointed to the right issue - comparator is not a valid CQL3 option, missed that. It was allowed in CQL2 and I had not realized it was removed in CQL3.